# Multiple select in select

Tags: mysql

I have a code like this:

```
SELECT column1 = (SELECT MAX(column-name21) FROM table-name2 WHERE condition2 GROUP BY id2) as m,
       column2 = (SELECT count(*) FROM table-name2 WHERE condition2 GROUP BY id2) as c,
       column-names
  FROM table-name
 WHERE condition
 ORDER BY ordercondition
 LIMIT 25,50
```

those internal selects are quite long and complicated.

My question is are there in mysql language contracts, which allow one to **avoid duplicating code and computations** in this case?

For example, something like this

```
SELECT (column1, column2) = (SELECT MAX(column-name1) as m, count(*) as c FROM table-name WHERE condition GROUP BY id),
       column-names
  FROM table-name
 WHERE condition
 ORDER BY ordercondition
 LIMIT 25,50
```

which of course won't be interpreted by mysql.

I tried this:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(column-name1) as column1, count(*) as column2 FROM table-name WHERE condition GROUP BY id),
       column-names
  FROM table-name
 WHERE condition
 ORDER BY ordercondition
 LIMIT 25,50
```

and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your 2nd query is a valid query (except the column names). Did you try it to check if it returns what you want?

Comment: @forpas so how do I do it? What's the code to combine them?

Comment: @forpas, I've added "the pseudocode" of the result, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I see that there are 2 tables involved but you do not mention how they are related. Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: You have no other column apart from the aggregate function in each query. Do you still have a specific reason to use group by in your sub-select?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, well i need to get the max and count values, and I can't get them w/o group by, can I?

Comment: Group by is only needed when you have some other column apart from the aggregate function. When you have only SUM and COUNT, You can select it without using the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such subqueries get cumbersome when you need more than one from the same source.  Usually, the "fix" is to us a "derived table" and `JOIN`:

```
SELECT x2.col1, x2.col2, names
    FROM ( SELECT  MAX(c21) AS col1,
                   COUNT(*) AS col2,
                   ??  -- may be needed for "cond2"
               FROM t2
               WHERE cond2a ) AS x2
    JOIN t1
        ON cond2b
    WHERE cond1
    ORDER BY ??? -- Limit is non-deterministic without ORDER BY
    LIMIT 25, 50
```

If the "condition" in the subquery is "correlated", please specify it; *it makes a big difference in how to transform the query*.

The construct `COUNT(col)` is usually a mistake:

```
COUNT(*) -- the number of rows.
COUNT(DISTINCT col)  -- the number of different values in column `col`.
COUNT(col) -- count the number of rows with non-NULL `col`.
```

Please provide your actual query and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I sloughed over several issues; "the devil is in the details".

**for Edit 1**

```
INDEX(tool, uuuuId)  -- would help performance
```

Is `uuuuId` some form of "hash" or "UUID"?  If so, that is relevant to seeing how the performance works.  Also, how big (approximately) are the tables?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  (I am fishing for whether you are I/O-bound or CPU-bound.)

`WZ` needs `INDEX(uuuuId, ppppppId, check1)`  But actually, that Select...=Yes can be turned and `EXISTS` for some speedup.

`Z` might benefit from `INDEX(check1, uuuuId, ppppppId, check2)`

Since Z and WZ are the same table, this might take care of both:

```
INDEX(ppppppId, uuuuId, check1, check2)
```

(The order is important.)

Comment: The join like this makes sense. But it seems like this way I lose a bit of execution speed. I've provided what I can in the new post edit. The full code would take just too much place. It's php+mysql, and a quite complicated code and I'm not allowed to reveal it.

Comment: @klm123 - `DESC` fails to say whether "MUL" describes two 1-column indexes or one 2-column index; _it makes a big difference_.  Hence my request for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: `SELECT f` and `SELECT flag` -- But those columns are not used?  I don't mind obfuscating sensitive SQL, but it needs to reflect enough of the real SQL to make sense.  The pattern for `EXISTS` is to simply say `SELECT 1` -- the value is ignored.  Saying "flag" confuses the reader.

Comment: I added some more tips.  Where possible, break out a subquery to see how fast it runs.  Then focus on a slow subquery instead of the complex complete query.

Comment: flag is the original name for f, which is missed.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, but I really would like to learn about my original question. From what I see here I conclude that there is no way to write *this exact query* down more elegantly. I.e. the way that it is more readable for humans and is exactly the same for the machine. Is this the correct conclusion?

Comment: @klm123 - Is performance an issue?  Is readability?  Sometimes readability is best handled by pumping data into temp tables, then acting on them.  Or, by using `WITH`.

Comment: the issue is that I'm not sure that I'm aware of all possible mysql contracts, which allow to write down queries elegantly :) Thereby the question was are there any other constructs, which would allow me to write down the query w/o duplicating code and duplicating computation.

Comment: Ok. The details I've provided has clearly increased the confusion and lead to misunderstanding that I want people to improve my specific case, not to provide me information about mysql language. So I had to remove all them from the question. Sorry about all that.